# Update xml parser 4 to 6

Tags: 2013-sp1, xml

I would like to update the XML parser from 4 to 6.
The reason for this is a vulnerability:
https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000009698

Upon deleting xml version 4 on Tridion 2013 SP1 I receive this error:
https://gateway.sdl.com/articles/SolutionArticles/000002660

How can I update legacy components to use xml parser 6 instead of 4, so I can delete version 4?

Kind regards,

Koen

Comment: I would reach out to SDL support, if there's really a vulnerability they should address it as long as there's support for 2013-sp1, which to be honest, might no longer be supported without an additional agreement. https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000003994

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to reach out directly to SDL Support. As of Jan 1st 2020, SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1 entered in the "extended support phase" as per the notification at https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/b/product-announcements/posts/sdl-tridion-2013-sp1-hr1-standard-support-extended-to-december-31-2019.

I'm not sure if SDL would then make public any resulting updates but I'm sure there's a few clients out there still on 2013 (hopefully in the midst of planning to upgrade to Sites 9.1).

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. I will reach out to support regarding this issue.